# MATLAB printing out a list of strings?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

having trouble with the following code which I thought would work:

```
OriginalSamples = {'BeforeWeDepart','ImSoGlad','NotToday', 'WellNowYouKnow'};
numOriginalSamples = length(OriginalSamples);

for i=1:numOriginalSamples
    disp(OriginalSamples(i));
end
```

Error I get is:

```
Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

How to do this simple operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `disp(OriginalSamples(i))` to `disp(OriginalSamples{i})`

Indexing with `()` returns a cell array, while indexing with `{}` return the content of the cell